# Domain of the Fisher z-transformation

Tags: statistics, transformation

We apply the fisher z-transformation to our correlation matrices, such that we arrive at approximately normally distributed data.

As you might now, the Fisher z-transformation is equivalent to the function

z = 0.5*log((1+x)/(1-x)), x being pearson's correlation coefficient, ranging between -1 and 1.

Now I have been told that fishers z has a domain between -4 and 4 - something which does not make sense to me, since when approximating 1 and -1 for the x values, we arrive at much bigger or smaller values respectively.

Have I been misinformed or am I missing out on something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For bivariate normal data Fisher's z  transformation is intended to have approximately a
normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ as shown
in the Wikipedia article on 'Fisher z transformation', which you should read.

A vast majority of the time, the standard normal
has values in $(\mu-4\sigma, \mu+4\sigma),$ but there may be occasional exceptions.
However, in the usual terminology, this would have to do with the $range$ of the transformation.

Anyhow, the interval $(-4, 4)$
may apply to many practical cases.
I don't know the full context of your question, but I'm having
trouble seeing how this could be a useful statement overall.

In the usual terminology the $domain$
must be $(-1, 1)$ for the values of the correlation being transformed.

So on several levels, what your source does not seem to have communicated sensible information.

Sometimes it helps to have an example. The simulation below
makes $m = 100,000$ datasets of $n = 12$ points. The
theoretical $\rho = .5$. Numerical descriptive statistics
summarize the $m$ values of $r$ and of $s$. You can compare
them with formulas in Wikipedia.

Graphs summarize the distributions
of the $m$ values of $r$ and of $z$; the best-fitting normal
density is shown for the second histogram; and a plot shows the 
domain and range of these values. For these plots
the $range$ of z values extends from -1 to 2.59.

```
 m = 10^5; r=numeric(m);  n = 12
 for(i in 1:m) {
    u1 = rnorm(n); u2 = rnorm(n);  u3=rnorm(n)
    x = u1 + u2;  y = u2 + u3
    r[i] = cor(x, y) }
 summary(r); sd(r)
 ##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 ## -0.7617  0.3428  0.5203  0.4837  0.6615  0.9888 
 ##  0.2392179
 z = .5*log((1+r)/(1-r))
 summary(z); sd(z)
 ##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 ## -1.0000  0.3573  0.5768  0.5769  0.7954  2.5910 
 ##  0.3318328
```

[image]